# Deleting files via SFTP

Tags: c#, sftp

Are there any C# open-source components that allow me to delete files via SFTP?

Comment: Just checking: by SFTP, do you mean the SSH file transfer protocol? Because that one has nothing to do with FTP, yet your question is tagged with FTP.

Comment: i disagree, SFTP and FTP are similar in some respects.

Comment: @djangofan Concepts are similar, but implementation is completely different. SFTP protocol has nothing in common with FTP (except name). See http://www.rebex.net/secure-ftp.net/ for differences between FTP, FTPS, FTP/SSL and SFTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Tamir Gal's [Sharp SSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) is quite popular open source implementation of SFTP for .NET. Give it a try.

If you preffer fully supported commercial component can try our [Rebex SFTP](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/). Following code ilustrates the concept:

```
using Rebex.Net;

// create client and connect  
Sftp client = new Sftp();
client.Connect(hostname);
client.Login(username, password);

// delete the file
client.DeleteFile("/path/to/the/file");

// disconnect  
client.Disconnect();
```

Comment: Martin, please disclose your affiliation in each post where you mention your own products.  I know you're not trying anything shady, this is just the policy that we're asking everyone to adhere to.  Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for the official policy statement.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I've added a magical 'our' word to this post (and to other posts too).

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenSSH and issue sftp batch commands.  All you have to do on the c# side is launch the sftp process with the correct command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using http://sshnet.codeplex.com/.   It has worked well for me and is actively being developed / supported.

The code to delete the file is as simple as

```
public static void DownloadFile(SftpClient client, SftpFile remoteFileName)
{
   var localFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(remoteFileName.Name );
   using (var file = File.OpenWrite(localFileName))
   {
       client.DownloadFile(remoteFileName.FullName , file);
       remoteFileName.Delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute Linux command rm with object SshExec.  This command delete file. 
Example:

rm /dir1/dir2/file.txt

Other Example [Tamir Execute Command](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/post/SshExec-Example.aspx)

```
public static bool DeleteFile(string remotePath) 
{
    try
    {
        SshExec comando = new SshExec(Server, User);
        comando.Password = Password;

        comando.Connect();

        string paso = comando.RunCommand("rm " + remotePath);

        comando.Close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        mErrorSFTP = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.